# Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed.

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis, smtp

When I try to send an email, I receive the following error:

```
Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed.
```

The email sends when I run it on my local machine but as soon as I upload it to IIS it stops working.

Below is my mail settings in my web.config file:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="">
        <network host="MyEmailServer" port="25" userName="" password=""/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

It also seems to work on my server but only sometimes.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a fix, could be useful if anyone sees this in the future. Instead of: `<network host="MyEmailServer" port="25" userName="" password=""/>` I did: `<network host="192.168.0.1" port="25" userName="" password=""/>` Where 192.168.0.1 is the IP address of the server. Hope it helps